# Concrete5: How can I display page attributes to specific page types?

Tags: concrete5

How can I display page attributes to specific page types in Properties? To avoid confusion to my clients, I don't want irrelevant page types showing up on all pages. Is there a way to achieve this?

I am using 5.6.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go to Page Types and then click Settings on the page type you can now pick the attributes you want to show. Although all attributes will show down the left hand side of a page these will show in the right ready to change

Comment: Actually I wanted to know if there is a way to limit attributes on the left hand side in the Properties. Looks like this is not possible.